# ASP.NET [Horizontal scroll fro GridView]

Tags: asp.net

how to make an horizontal scroll for my large GridView ?

Comment: Hello, I don't remeber what is this link was about, this question is very old and it's already answered. If you have any related troubles I suggest you to open new question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try wrapping a `<div style="overflow-x:auto;width:800px">  </div>` around the GridView.